# Elasticsearch pagination with WHERE condition and Group By

Tags: elasticsearch, group-by, pagination, group

I want to group by contact_id to get all unique contact_id.

Group by contact_id

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_contact_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "contact_id",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to apply filter last_active >= '2024-01-01' and then group by contact_id. I want to paginate through all grouped contact_ids. Also I want to get the total_group_contact_ids based on filter ?

I have tried to get the total group by contact_id but it is not according to filter

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_contact_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "contact_id",
        "size": 10 
      }
    },
    "total_group_count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "contact_id"
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,   
  "size": 10   
}
```

also the pagination is giving me wrong results